# JQuery: How do you access the key names in a JSON array?

Tags: jquery, json, key

In JQuery, I'm attempting to access the key names in a JSON array. What I have is this:

```
response = '[{"file":"app.dll", "fields": {"name":"Misc App", "rank":1}}]';
response = JSON.parse(response);
```

How would I go about accessing the key names in the places of "file" and "name"?

Answer (score 0):

You'd get `file` and `fields` with `Object.keys(response)`. You'd need to do `Object.keys(response.fields)` to get `name` and `rank`.

It might make more sense to explain your goal. Ideally you wouldn't have to do this.

Comment: I'm attempting to update a dropdown list based on the users selection.
For example:
Country:United States
States:{Alabama:AL,California:CA}
etc